# Using subselect to Join Two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, I want to reduce the amount of time it takes to compare records between the two tables. I am not able to inner join my two table because they are both longitudinal table, meaning animalid can be duplicated several even though it is unique to a milk record

Table 1(my error table)

```
+-----+----------+---------+---------+------------+
| #ID | animalid | milkmor | milkeve |  milkdate  |
+-----+----------+---------+---------+------------+
|   1 | animal_A |      12 |      12 | 2019-09-12 |
|   2 | animal_A |      12 |      13 | 2018-09-12 |
+-----+----------+---------+---------+------------+
```

Table 2(my accurate record table)

```
+-----+----------+---------+---------+------------+
| #ID | animalid | milkmor | milkeve |  milkdate  |
+-----+----------+---------+---------+------------+
|   1 | animal_A |      12 |      12 | 2017-09-12 |
|   2 | animal_A |      12 |      13 | 2018-09-12 |
+-----+----------+---------+---------+------------+
```

I want to compare the two table and only display records from table 1 which are unique, the uniquness is made of both animalid and milkdate

The following is my sub-select query

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2
WHERE  table1.animalid = table2.animalid AND table1.milkdate <> table2.milkdate
```

The expected output:

```
+----+----------+---------+---------+------------+
| ID | animalid | milkmor | milkeve |  milkdate  |
+----+----------+---------+---------+------------+
|  1 | animal_A |      12 |      12 | 2019-09-12 |
+----+----------+---------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: I am unclear what you are asking for. Are you simply interested in table1 records which don't exist in table2?

Comment: I tried with the combination of `ID`, `animalid` in SQL Server, is [this helpful](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0354a65c4825c259f53bdbef25680d82) for you?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this

```
drop table if exists t,t2;
create table t (ID  int, animalid varchar(20), milkmor int, milkeve int,  milkdate  date);
create table t2 (ID  int, animalid varchar(20), milkmor int, milkeve int,  milkdate  date);
insert into t values
(   1 , 'animal_A' ,      12 ,      12 , '2019-09-12'),
(   2 , 'animal_A' ,      12 ,      13 , '2018-09-12');
insert into t2 values
(   1 , 'animal_A' ,      12 ,      12 , '2017-09-12'), 
(   2 , 'animal_A' ,      12 ,      13 , '2018-09-12'); 

select distinct t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t2 where t2.animalid = t.animalid and t2.milkdate = t.milkdate);    

+------+----------+---------+---------+------------+
| ID   | animalid | milkmor | milkeve | milkdate   |
+------+----------+---------+---------+------------+
|    1 | animal_A |      12 |      12 | 2019-09-12 |
+------+----------+---------+---------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```